# Material Datepicker two way binding with ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a stepper process form and on the first step the user is asked to pick a date using the Angular Material design `Datepicker` component.

When the user goes to the next step I want to bind the value they selected and show it again at the top in an input field (they should be able to change it here as well).

I've tried `[(ngModel)]` but not sure if I'm using it properly.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input [(ngModel)]="date" formControlName="dateFormCtrl" matInput 
      [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" 
      placeholder="When is your event?" readonly> 
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle> 
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker> 
  <mat-error>The input is required.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Check the [Datepicker selected value](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) example from the official docs

Comment: check [this](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#input-and-change-events)

Answer (score 0):

Use `[formControl]="dateFormCtrl"`

**Example:**

```
<input [formControl]="dateFormCtrl" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" placeholder="When is your event?" readonly>
```

In the `.ts` file you should have a variable `dateFormCtrl`.

```
dateFormCtrl = new FormControl(new Date()); // this will display your date in the picker
```

Now to access the value anywhere use `dateFormCtrl.value`.

In your case you can also show by `[value]="dateFormCtrl.value"` in the input of `datepicker`.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 4 and 5, it possible to use `ngModel` in [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). However, to future-proof the design, it is better to reference the value of the `FormControl` directly, assuming that you wish to use reactive forms rather than template-driven forms.

#### [Angular Docs for `FormControlName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)

> Support for using the `ngModel` input property and `ngModelChange` event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.
>
> Now deprecated:
>
> ```
> <form [formGroup]="form">
>   <input formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="value">
> </form>
> ```

### Datepicker Component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerExample implements OnInit {
  myGroup: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myGroup = this.fb.group({
      dateFormCtrl: new FormControl(new Date())
    })
  }
}
```

## Datepicker Template

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="dateFormCtrl" [matDatepicker]="picker"  
      placeholder="When is your event?" readonly>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    Selected date:
    <input matInput [value]="myGroup.get('dateFormCtrl').value | date">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Christopher-Peisert.  I had problems getting the DatePicker to bind to the control.  I am not using ngModel. I am using Angular FormBuilder, and dynamically adding controls.
When I added `[formControlName]="nameVariable"` to:

```js
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [formControlName]="control.name" [value]="control.value"/>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle> 
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

the angular material datepicker bound to my control.  Now, I can populate date value from server, and when changed by user, new value updates my control, and is accessible from myForm.value.

Thank you @Eliseo.  I removed `[value]="control.value"` from
`<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [formControlName]="control.name"`
it works well, and is easier for me to understand.

Comment: if you use formControlName, **not** use [value]